# How to go forward/backward from a specific date in PANDASQL e.g. as in oracle date-1 ,and in impala DAYS_ADD(date,-1)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, pandasql

I am new to python and I am using `pandasql` to perform condition-based joins:

```
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

q = """
    SELECT *
        FROM
            a_Df A
        INNER JOIN
            b_Df B
        ON 
            a.effective_date between b.effective_date-5 and b.effective_date
            and a.id =b.id
    """
pj = pysqldf(q)
```

This query is basically for scaling date from `effective_date-5` and current `effective_date`, but this is not functioning in the expected order
i.e. Let's say current `effective_date` is '2021-03-21' then `effective_date-5` is giving 2016 instead of '2021-03-16', hence I am not getting the desire output.

So the query becomes:

```
q = """
        SELECT *
            FROM
                a_Df A
            INNER JOIN
                b_Df B
            ON 
                a.effective_date between '2016' and '2021-03-21'
                and a.id =b.id
"""
```

instead of

```
q = """
        SELECT *
            FROM
                a_Df A
            INNER JOIN
                b_Df B
            ON 
                a.effective_date between '2021-03-16' and '2021-03-21'
                and a.id =b.id
    """
```

and as the dateset is huge I cannot perform hardcoded changes.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

as this `pandasql/sqldf` work on `sqlite` so anyone can try any function that `sqlite` support, hence the syntax would be like this..

```
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

q = """
    SELECT *
        FROM
            a_Df A
        INNER JOIN
            b_Df B
        ON 
            a.effective_date between date(b.effective_date, '-5 day')and b.effective_date
            and a.id =b.id
    """
pj = pysqldf(q)
```